# For loop exiting after one loop - MPI

Tags: c, loops

I'm working on a send/receive MPI program and for some reason the loop only iterates once and then exits.  Does anyone have any idea why?

The code:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int rank;
    int b2, a1;
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
        if (rank == 0) {
            a1 = 10;
            MPI_Sendrecv(&a1, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 99,
                    &b2, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 99,
                    MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

        } else {
            a1 = 20;
            MPI_Sendrecv(&a1, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 99,
                    &b2, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 99,
                    MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        }
    }

    printf("Process %d: received %d\n", rank, b2);
    MPI_Finalize();

}
```

The output (This should be repeating multiple times but this is all I get):

```
Process 1: received 10
Process 0: received 20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `printf()` is not in the loop.  It is no surprise that it is only printed once.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that.  Thank you.